# Optimization of Python comprehension expression

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I was trying to get the frequency of max value in an integer list (intlist)

```
intlist.count(max(intlist))
```

this works and is good in speed as well.

I wanted to implement the max method with comprehension,-

```
[x if x>y else y for x in intlist for y in intlist if x!=y][-1]
```

the later turns out to be very slow.
Can any one point out what is the issue here.
testing with

```
intlist=np.array([1, 2, 3,3,-1])
```

in this case the value expected is 2 as 3 is the max value and it occurs 2 times.

Comment: Are those all integers in that array for your actual use-case?

Comment: You way to calculate a `max`imum will not work, since the last item in the list comprehension will just be the maximum of the latest two numbers in the arrays that are different, but not per se the largest value globally.

Comment: Think you can use `np.count_nonzero(intlist==intlist.max())` for generic case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list comprehension will not calculate the maximum value in the first place. Indeed, it will here calculate the maximum of *two* values from `intlist` of the latest values. So unless the last two items in the list are the same, it will calculate the maximum of the *last* two values.

Furthermore it is not very efficient, since it runs in *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* time, and *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* memory. For huge lists, this would thus require gigantic amounts of memory.

Usually it is not a good idea to use list comprehension if you do not need a list in the first place. You can calculate a maximum with a `for` loop, where you each time compare an item with the thus far obtained maximum:

```
def other_max(listlike):
    mmax = listlike[0]
    for x in listlike:
        if x > mmax:
            mmax = x
    return mmax
```

or with numpy we can sum up the array of booleans:

```
>>> (intlist == intlist.max()).sum()
2
```

Comment: thanks.more of an experiment trying to understand comprehension . then i hit up on the slowness. Wanted to understand why it is slow more than whether it is working or not. But i appreciate all the points here.